# Reverse sort a 2d dictionary based on value

Tags: python

I have a 2d dictionary where my data looks like:

```
k1,k2, value
 1,2,0.8
 1,3,0.7
 1,5,0.9
 2,1,0.8

  and so on
```

So lets say I have this data in 2d dict..

```
d[1][2] --> gives 0.8
```

What I want is to reverse sort k2 for each k1 based on value

So for above.. what i am hoping to get after this operation is:

```
1,5,0.9
1,2,0.8
1,3,0.7
2,1,0.8
```

and so on..

How do i achive the above in python

Comment: Please post the dict.

Comment: Your question seems contradictory. Do you want to reverse sort on `k2`, or on `value`? (Also, do you want to sort on `k1`, or just get them in arbitrary order?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reverse-sorts on `k2` for each `k1`, which is what your question asks for:

```
for k1, subdict in maindict.items():
    for k2, value in sorted(subdict.items(), reverse=True):
        print(k1, k2, value)
```

If you also want to forward-sort on `k1`:

```
for k1, subdict in sorted(maindict.items()):
    for k2, value in sorted(subdict.items(), reverse=True):
        print(k1, k2, value)
```

If you want to reverse-sort on `value` instead of `k2` (as your title asks for):

```
for k1, subdict in maindict.items():
    for k2, value in sorted(subdict.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v, reverse=True):
        print(k1, k2, value)
```

Some explanation:

You can call [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) on any sequence to get a sorted version of it. You can pass `reverse=True` to almost any sorting-related function to sort it in reverse, and `key` to specify a function that generates a sorting key from each value. See the [Sorting HOW TO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) for details.

(The `lambda` function given above only works for Python 2.x. In 3.x, you can use `lambda kv: kv[1]`. Or you can just use `operator.itemgetter(1)`.)

And you can get a sequence of key-value pairs out of any mapping by calling its [`items`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method. In Python 3.x, this gives you a nice efficient view; in 2.x, it copies the pairs into a `list`.

Finally, keep in mind that a `dict` has no inherent order.

Answer (score 1):

The point of a dict is that it is unordered. If you want to create a new list of the values from your dict, and have those values sorted, that's a different thing. But you're not going to get a dictionary that has been sorted (unless you make yourself a sorted dict, which isn't actually that hard).